# Adding custom fonts in mosaico

Tags: message-templates, mailing, civicrm-home, mosaico

Basicly what it says in the title. How do I add custom fonts within mosaico templates, i.e. how do I make them selectable in the template design process?

There is the answer to my question on [github](https://github.com/voidlabs/mosaico/issues/267) and it goes like this:

> In the header of the template (the mso comments are there because
>   Outlook is able to read webfonts declaration but then "breaks" any
>   declared font):
>
> ```
> <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
> <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Your+Web+Font" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
> <!--<![endif]-->
> ```
>
> In the @supports -ko-blockdefs section of your template you add your
>   font to the select box:
>
> ```
>   face { label: Font; widget: select; options: Your Web Font, Fallback, serif=Your Web Font|Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif=Arial|Arial
> ```
>
> Black, Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif=Arial Black|Comic Sans MS,
>   Comic Sans MS5, cursive=Comic Sans|Courier New, Courier New,
>   monospace=Courier|Georgia, serif=Georgia|Impact,
>   sans-serif=Impact|Lucida Console, Monaco, monospace=Lucida
>   Console|Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif=Lucida Sans
>   Unicode|Times New Roman, Times, serif=Times New Roman|Verdana, Geneva,
>   sans-serif=Verdana}

However this doesn't work for me. When I add this to versafix-1 (mosaico/templates/versafix-1/template-versafix-1.html) I still don't have the font I specified.

Here's the begining of versafix-1 template I eddited

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <title style="-ko-bind-text: @titleText">TITLE</title>
  <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
    @supports -ko-blockdefs {
      id { widget: id }
      size { label: Size; widget: select; options: 8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|18|20|22|25|28|31; }
      visible { label: Visible?; widget: boolean }
      color { label: Color; widget: color }
      radius {
        label: Corner Radius;
        widget: integer;
        max: 20;
        help: Attention - this property is not supported on all email clients (i.e. Outlook)
      face { label: Font; widget: select; options: Open Sans, Arial, serif=Open Sans|Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif=Arial|Arial Black, Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif=Ari$
      }
```

Comment: look fwd to the answer. we also had a question just recently from a client about changing line-spacing but haven't gotten round to digging on that yet

Comment: Did you make any progress on this question? I would be interested as well!

Comment: A long time ago now, but if anyone is looking in the future: simply change the options for lineHeight in the versafix template.
It looks like this:       lineHeight { label: Line Height; widget: select; options: normal=Normal|150%=1.5 Lines|200%=Double; },
changing those percentages will change the options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What worked for me with google-fonts is the following:

After the  tag add the include path generated from google-fonts, in this example Modak and Open Sans.

```
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Modak|Open+Sans');
```

Then in the @supports block, in the face part add the fonts separated by '|', to be included in the blocks:

```
  face { label: Font; widget: select; options: Arial|Impact|'Open Sans', sans-serif|Times New Roman|'Modak'}
```

Edit: local fonts can be included by putting them on accessible on your server, and then import them in the template like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'your_font_name';
  src: url(https://example.com/files/fonts/your_font/your_font_file.ttf) format('ttf'), 
    url(https://example.com/files/fonts/your_font/your_font_file.woff2) format('woff2');
        }
```

Then add those to the dropdown menu in the @supports block same as above.

That way your fonts can be loaded from your server.

Comment: Clearing browser cache was also needed. This was the main cause of my troubles. Even when I had the right solution, I couldn't see it because of the cache.

Comment: yeah, that's always a good idea when handeling JS, and happened to me as well a couple of times! :|

Comment: Whilst not specific to Mosaico this guide to the use of web fonts by Litmus is very informative: https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts

Answer (score 2):

I answered this the other day when I was looking at adding the Trebuchet MS font and came across a question on adding Google Fonts (see [Import Google fonts in Mosaico](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/42282/6361))

I'm using the latest Mosaico (2.9.1645644008) and my versafix-1 template looked a little different.  The changes I made were basically the same as above but without using @font-face:

1. Make a copy (if you want to, I did!) of the existing versafix-1 template
2. Add the @import link from Google's font pages ([Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/))
3. Add the additonal font/s to the @supports -ko-blockdefs section

Re 1. I did not use an extension, just added a directory called mosaico_tpl. The correct directory name is defined in the Mosaico Settings:  Administer > CiviMail > Mosaico Settings. The default is [civicrm.files]/mosaico_tpl.  I copied the entire versafix-1 directory and subdirectories to mosaico_tpl.  This gave me the template, template-versafix-1.html, along with the edres and img resource directories.  I just renamed the the directory and template file to suit.

Here is copy of the section of the template html files I edited:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <title style="-ko-bind-text: @titleText">[subject]</title>
  
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap'); 
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pontano+Sans&display=swap');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+SC:wght@300&display=swap');
    @supports -ko-blockdefs {
      id { widget: id }
      size { label: Size; widget: select; options: 8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|18|20|22|25|28|31; }
      visible { label: Visible?; widget: boolean }
      color { label: Color; widget: color }
      radius {
        label: Corner Radius;
        widget: integer;
        max: 20;
        help: Attention - this property is not supported on all email clients (i.e. Outlook)
      }
      face { label: Police; widget: select; options: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif=Trebuchet MS|Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif=Arial|Arial Black, Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif=Arial Black|Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans MS5, cursive=Comic Sans|Courier New, Courier New, monospace=Courier|Georgia, serif=Georgia|Impact, sans-serif=Impact|Lucida Console, Monaco, monospace=Lucida Console|Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif=Lucida Sans Unicode|Nunito, sans-serif=Nunito|Pontano sans, sans-serif=Pontano Sans|Times New Roman, Times, serif=Times New Roman|Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif=Verdana|Cormorant SC}
      decoration { label: Decoration; widget: select; options: none=None|underline=Underline }
      linksColor { label: Link Color; extend: color }
```

I had no need to import Trebuchet MS, but you will see that I imported 3 google fonts - Nunito, Pontano and Cormorant SC.

In the face {... block, each typeface is seperated by a | character and you define your fallback as the second parameter -  *typeface*, *fallback* e.g. Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif=Trebuchet MS.  In this example from above, Helvetica is the fallback. The | character then ends that typeface and the next one is defined.

As I quickly learned, you **MUST** clear your caches, I did both Drupal and CiviCRM to see the changes, but all worked first time for me on Drupal 7.9, CiviCRM 5.50.1.

As a complete aside I came across this today for when I'm feeling adventurous and brave enough to start doing more with these templates:

[Adding a custom block to Mosaico email editor in CiviCRM](https://artfulrobot.uk/blog/adding-custom-block-mosaico-email-editor-civicrm#comment-4252)