# Where does Mosaico store my templates?

Tags: templates, mosaico

Setting up Mosaico. I have created a new template from one of the existing base templates. I save my new template, which now appears as a 'configured template'. I'd like to tweak the code for this new template, but I can't find the template on my server. Mosaico Settings suggests that it might be in [civicrm.files]/mosaico_tpl, but no such directory exists on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templates are stored in your CiviCRM database in the table civicrm_mosaico_msg_template. They are not saved as actual files. BTW Im assuming you are using the Mosaico extension?
If you go to CiviCRM->Mailings->Mosiaco Templates you get full options for tweaking existing templates, copying them and so on. See attached image.[image]

Comment: Thanks Tony. I'd assumed this was the likely situation after I posted. I was after adding in two custom fonts, and have now found out how to do that by editing the relevant base template file, as at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/adding-custom-fonts-in-mosaico/20808