# How to add a Google font to Mosaico?

Tags: mosaico

I want to add a Google font called 'Red Hat Display' to Mosaico, to the versafix-1 template. The answer in the question [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/adding-custom-fonts-in-mosaico) doesn't appear to work. There's been a few Mosaico releases since then, hence I think it's worth raising this as a new question, as I think file structures within the Mosaico extension may have changed etc, and this is specific to a Google font which I would guess is a popular option. So if anyone has done this a guide would be very useful.  Thanks!

Comment: Which version of mosaico are you using?

Comment: The latest, 2.5 or to be precise 2.5.1597918155!

Comment: Yeah I have the same version. The method in the post you linked works. You did something wrong. I suggest you try again. Don't forget to clear your browser cache once you make changes.

Comment: Did you update the file template-versafix-1.html in the folder civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/templates/versafix-1/img ? I notice that I have the extra folder 'img' .

Comment: If that's the correct file then the problem might be that I don't understand the structure/syntax of the 'face' statement where I am adding 'Red Hat Display'.  Could you post your 'face' statement that works, please?  Thanks

Comment: Here's the entire file https://pastebin.com/1Z8SgsvF with several gogole fonts.

Comment: Many thanks! That's very helpful