# Import Google fonts in Mosaico

Tags: mosaico

I've followed some posts found [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/adding-custom-fonts-in-mosaico) and [there](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/38393/how-to-add-a-google-font-to-mosaico) but wasn't able to make that work on Mosaico 2.8. Here is what I've added to versafix template.

Have missed something obvious?

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap'); @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pontano+Sans&display=swap');`

`face { label: Police; widget: select; options: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif=Arial|Arial Black, Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif=Arial Black|Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans MS5, cursive=Comic Sans|Courier New, Courier New, monospace=Courier|Georgia, serif=Georgia|Impact, sans-serif=Impact|Lucida Console, Monaco, monospace=Lucida Console|Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif=Lucida Sans Unicode|Nunito, sans-serif=Nunito|Pontano sans, sans-serif=Pontano Sans|Times New Roman, Times, serif=Times New Roman|Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif=Verdana}`

Answer (score 1):

Did you clear all your caches?

I just tried this and it worked for me using your code example. I copied the @import lines before the @supports -ko-blockdefs section and then your font select options afterwards:

```
...
<style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap'); 
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pontano+Sans&display=swap');
    @supports -ko-blockdefs {
      id { widget: id }
      size { label: Size; widget: select; options: 8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|18|20|22|25|28|31; }
      visible { label: Visible?; widget: boolean }
      color { label: Color; widget: color }
      radius {
        label: Corner Radius;
        widget: integer;
        max: 20;
        help: Attention - this property is not supported on all email clients (i.e. Outlook)
      }
      face { label: Police; widget: select; options: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif=Arial|Arial Black, Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif=Arial Black|Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans MS5, cursive=Comic Sans|Courier New, Courier New, monospace=Courier|Georgia, serif=Georgia|Impact, sans-serif=Impact|Lucida Console, Monaco, monospace=Lucida Console|Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif=Lucida Sans Unicode|Nunito, sans-serif=Nunito|Pontano sans, sans-serif=Pontano Sans|Times New Roman, Times, serif=Times New Roman|Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif=Verdana}
      decoration { label: Decoration; widget: select; options: none=None|underline=Underline }
      linksColor { label: Link Color; extend: color }
...
```

I did this, cleared both the Drupal and the CiviCRM cache and all was fine?

Comment: yes, it worked fine by the end!