# How to use Open Sans font iin Mosaico

Tags: mosaico, google

I want to migrate to Mosaico from MailChimp but need the Open Sans font. Where might I find the relevant code and in which folder will I find the file to insert the code?
Thanks

Comment: I had tweaked Mosaico to use non-standard fonts that I use on the website. But have since stopped doing that because not all mail clients support the use of - for example - Google fonts.

Answer (score 0):

This previous [SE post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/adding-custom-fonts-in-mosaico) has some pretty detailed guidance on how to import Google Fonts